# Can I run the Unity launcher in GNOME 3?

Tags: unity, gnome, unity-dash

I would like to use GNOME 3 with the Unity launcher and dash. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: and  sorry for my lak of knowleadg :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really mix both, but there's a GNOME Shell extension that replicates the Unity launcher and Dash: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/330/bolt/

You might also want to try this: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

Comment: Does it have side bar or it is only dash.

Comment: thnx very much liked it :3

Comment: but can i atlist resize the unity top panel ???? and thnx again

Comment: I'm not sure, since I can't try it myself. If it's only the dash, you can use the second extension I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gnome extention [bolt](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/330/bolt/)  with `docky` in left hand side running in panel mode just like  unity side bar.